# Mechanism for efficiently storing "coordinates"

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, memory

While working on a hobby project of mine i'm trying to find a most "efficiently" solution for the following issue. Before I'll describe the issue I want to say I was not sure if I had to post this in the https://math.stackexchange.com/ section or here in the https://stackoverflow.com/ section. So if I'm in the wrong section, sorry about that! ;)

**Issue description:**

I have a file containing elements, these elements can be represented by coordinates. These coordinates consists of two unsigned integers, for example: `0,2` `6,3` or `1,157348`. All the coordinates representing a element in the file is unique for the given file. What I would like to achieve is creating a mapping for these coordinates so I can access them quickly. A very straightforward solution would be to create a collection which to store the coordinates as a pair. for example:

```
$collection = [0 => [0,2],1 => [6,3], 2 => [1,157348], ...];
```

The problem with this solution is (I assume) that vast numbers of elements that the file *can* contain. In my case it is very likely that the file contains hundreds of thousands of elements, leaving me with a very large mapping collection. This could possibly cause memory issues for the application and so crashing the application.

I think storing the coordinates of a element as a paired array is inefficiently. I think a more memory efficient solution would be if I could encode the coordinates of an element as a single value which is again decodeable for getting the real element coordinates.

A solution would be to store the coordinates as strings. for example:

```
$collection = [0 => '0;2', 1 => '6;3', 2 => '1;157348', ...];
```

This leaves me with a single dimensional array, that should be more memory efficient than the multi-dimensional solution before. Which is awesome. But this solution would require some extra steps:

Writing:

1. encoding integers to string and separate them by a token (`;`)

Reading:

1. decoding string, separate the string token (`;`).
2. casting the coordinate values back to integers.

Maybe it would be cool if these steps could be avoided. and I don't think storing the coordinates as a floats, because of the (possible) very large decimal part.

So I was thinking, I can't imagine being the first person to encounter this kind  problem, is there a way (like: algorithm) that is capable of converting two integer values to a single integer value, and can be reconverted to the the original values by computation.

From the way I seeing it, this would have the following advantages:

- No int -> string or string -> int conversion needed.
- Storing the value as integer is more efficient than string storage.

A disadvantage would be:

- Computing the coordinates to a single value and back, would require more CPU power, slowing down the application.

I would prefer a slower solution against a more memory inefficient solution, because I expect (putting it simply) a memory inefficient solution increases the risk of crashing the application where a more CPU intensive solution just increases the time taking the system to process the file.

So does anybody has a clue if such algorithm exists? Or do you have a idea of another way of solving this problem I would be happy to hear your ideas.

If you think that my assumptions are incorrectly, please correct me in a constructive manner ;-)

Comment: Converting int to string isn't necessary memory efficient. Well, in few cases, it's memory efficient. in a string (ASCII encoded), a character is 1 byte. An integer is 4 bytes. `"99999"` is 5 bytes (6 if there's a last character `\0` like in C) while `99999` is 4 bytes.

Comment: Have you considered adding this data to a database table? You could then use indices that improve the speed of operations

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have the entire collection loaded in php? If you don't, you can use Redis (https://redis.io/) to store the collection and just query for the values that you need. Would help if you'd provide some more details about what you use the values for.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I will try to review them and come back to you with my chosen method.

Im trying to create some kind of  JSON parser. Note: I know its reinventing the wheel. But the process is very interesting and full of thing to learn from.